# Print with Background Color and Images on Node-Webkit

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, printing, node-webkit

I´m trying to print a node-webkit application page using `windows.print()` on a button.
I already created a separate CSS file just to print it with all the style I want.

When I click the button and choose my printer (without preview, unfortunately), none of my CSS is loaded. By using the console emulation (F12 on Chrome) to see how the page will look on a print, the CSS is there!

I´ve seen something similar when programming a Rails app but, to fix it, I just had to mark the "Background graphics" option on Chrome. [image]

Since Node-Webkit does not have the print preview, how do I print my CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the trick by using `!important` and `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` on my CSS.